# How can I set a timeout on "return false"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function, where I disable all my links:

```
$("a").click(function() { 
    return false; 
});
```

But I want to disable them only for one second and then enable them again. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to disable them for a second while the page loads or have them click, wait a second and then go anyway?

Comment: Hello, the click doesn't  direct to a new page. Just all links should e disabled for a second. It is not on pageload-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible with some use of jQuery and `setTimeout`. There are quite a few ways to achieve a similar result, but I crafted an example which adds classes to allow for some granular targeting on your elements if you wish to do so. You'll get some additional benefits for free going to route as well, such as styling your disabled links if you wish (I did so in the example). Observe the following...

```
<a href="#">link</a>
<a href="#">link</a>
<button>disable</button>
```

---

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('a').addClass('disabled')

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.disabled').removeClass('disabled')
        }, 1000);
    })

    $('body').delegate('.disabled', 'click', function() { 
        console.log('disabled')
        return false; 
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gc619upg/) - demo

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the redirect to take place one second after the click event you can prevent the default redirect caused by the click event and then do the same redirect later using `window.location`

```
$("a").click(function () {
    var url = this.href;
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location = url;
    }, 1000)
    return false;
});
```

Note that the expected behavior is not very clear in question

Comment: Hello, I do not want to redirect to another page. Just on click on a link I want to disable all links

Comment: That isn't very clear. Please update question with a full explanation of expected behavior